# How can I make an animation after Pageload

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to create a page where the animations will be seen while scrolling down the page, not at once.

I've already created a page with four css3 animations. It's animating now at once while the pages loads. I want it to animate when scrolling down the page.

I've heard that jquery can do it, But i can't implement there.

I've tried jquery but not working. kindly help.

Here is my faulty codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#one").delay(100).fadeInUp();
        $("#two").delay(300).fadeInDown();
        $("#three").delay(600).fadeInRight();
        $("#four").delay(700).fadeInLeft();
        $("body").delay(500).queue(function(next){$(this).addClass("fadeInUp");next();})
    })
```

The divs #one, #two, #three and #four each has an animation. It's animating at once. But i want it to load when scrolling down. just like: http://knockknockfactory.com  .  The codes are available at Github. see above please.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to Edited Question**

This is the same principle as before, just triggered when you scroll down a number of `px` rather than to a specific `div`

**Animations**

- [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) -Wicked cool plug and play CSS animations

**API Documentation**

- [.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)
- [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)
- [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)
- [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/6Y9qX/4/)**

```
$(document).scroll(function () {

    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > (200)) {
        $(".magic").fadeIn('fast').addClass("fadeInDown").removeClass("fadeOutUp");
    }
    if ((y < (200)) && $('.magic').hasClass('fadeInDown')) {
        $(".magic").addClass("fadeOutUp").removeClass("fadeInDown").fadeOut('slow');
    }
    //magic2  
    if (y > (300)) {
        $(".magic2").fadeIn('fast').addClass("fadeInRight").removeClass("fadeOutRight");
    }
    if ((y < (300)) && $('.magic2').hasClass('fadeInRight')) {
        $(".magic2").addClass("fadeOutRight").removeClass("fadeInRight").fadeOut('slow');
    }
    //magic3
    if (y > (400)) {
        $(".magic3").fadeIn('fast').addClass("fadeInLeft").removeClass("fadeOutLeft");
    }
    if ((y < (400)) && $('.magic3').hasClass('fadeInLeft')) {
        $(".magic3").addClass("fadeOutLeft").removeClass("fadeInLeft").fadeOut('slow');
    }
    //magic4
    if (y > (500)) {
        $(".magic4").fadeIn('fast').addClass("fadeInUp").removeClass("fadeOutDown");
    }
    if ((y < (500)) && $('.magic4').hasClass('fadeInUp')) {
        $(".magic4").addClass("fadeOutDown").removeClass("fadeInUp").fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

**Answer to Original Question**

Page load animations are completely do-able in css alone. 
Just set up a keyframe animation and attach it to an element and when that element loads the animation will do its thing.

Animations triggered by the user scrolling down to an element will require a little jquery.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
var x = $("#myDiv").position();

if (y > (x.top - 28)) {
    $(".magic").addClass(
        "bounceInRight");
}
else {
    $(".magic").removeClass(
        "bounceInRight");
}
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/vfQrD/6/)

Comment: Yes, the above javascript will work but I've already figured it out with css3 keyframes animation. It really cool. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can you kindly show me a demo page that an element will come from left side, another is from right side and another is from the bottom. not at a time, it should come one by one.

Comment: @EbrahimKhalil Check out [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/), for the animations, then you can play with the timing using `animation-delay:`

Comment: Ho again, thanks for animate.css , although i knew css3 keyframes animation. anyway, I can't use jquery there. can you help me on github ? I've uploaded those just for you to get help. Here is the link: https://github.com/Ebrahim6/loading-animation    . Just download and make an onload transition. I've already added the css files. It's now loading at once. But  want it to load when scrolling down the page. Any help is really appreciable.

Comment: @EbrahimKhalil If you have a specific question ask it on SO and I may be able to help. If you need a complete build you may need to hire someone.

Comment: okay here is my specific question: I've four divs:  #one = fadeInUp, #two = fadeInDown, #three = fadeinRight , #four = fadeInLeft  .                 What will be the jquery code to load these animation while scrolling down ?    <script>  ???  </script>

Comment: @EbrahimKhalil post your question as a question, not a comment, and I'll be glad to take a look.

Comment: @EbrahimKhalil Glad to help.  Next time, if you need more information ask a new question. People may see it as rude if you edit a question to the point that it makes the answers already given incorrect.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm new in Stack Overflow. So, I'll correct myslef. Thanks!

Comment: one issue, It's working on jsfiddle well but not working in my desktop after collecting the codes in html page. I can't understand what's missing...

Answer (score 0):

You only technically need javascript, doing something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
//put animation code here
}
```

The animation itself may need jQuery, though. CSS3 won't do anything on load as far as I know.

Comment: You don't even need window.onload, actually. You can simply put the JS/jQuery at the bottom of the page, right before the ending body tag, and it'll start right when the page is loaded.

Comment: Cool tip, I didn't know that. However, it feels like `window.onload` would be more stable.

Comment: It may feel more stable, but directly executing code is just as stable (if not more stable) than executing that same code from an event handler callback function.

Comment: Hi HartleySan and Wilson, I can't use jquery there. can you help me on github ? I've uploaded those just for you to get help. Here is the link: github.com/Ebrahim6/loading-animation . Just download and make an onload transition. I've already added the css files. It's now loading at once. But want it to load when scrolling down the page. Any help is really appreciable